# SDL stopped creating stdout.txt and stderr.txt

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been using the stdout.txt and stderr.txt files that SDL directs output to for the last couple months.  I've always been able to read debugging information in them, but starting today, the files no longer get created.  The program runs normally, but when execution stops, the files disappear.  Does anyone know of a simple reason why this might be happening?  I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

EDIT:  The stderr.txt file just started appearing again.  I think I found the source of the problem.  I had added /NODEFAULTLIB:library to the command line arguments because I was getting the following warning message:

```
warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; 
use/NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

When I removed the command, the output files started appearing again, but I still get the warning message.  Can someone explain this to me?  Should I just ignore the warning, or is there a way to get rid of the warning, yet keep the SDL redirected output?

Comment: Do you build SDL yourself? The problem you mention in your edit is due to differing versions of the CRT being used, which most commonly is a result of either different versions of VC being used for building the library and the application, or different kinds of the CRT (Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library.) Another common cause of this kind of warning is using "Debug" build of libraries with a "Release" build of application or the other way around. Could you check that this is not what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, when you build SDL, it gives you another library (besides `SDL.lib`) named `SDLmain.lib`.

You can build this library so it *doesn't redirect standard streams to files*. It uses the preprocessor definition `NO_STDIO_REDIRECT`, i.e., when this symbol is defined, the standard streams are not redirected to file.

So, if you build SDL yourself, you can check your solution files to see whether this symbol is defined somewhere or not. I just checked the provided solutions in the SDL source code and while versions before VC11 (Visual Studio 2012) do have configurations to build SDLmain with and without STDIO redirect, VC11 solutions *do not*.

I don't know what's happening with the SDL. Maybe they are phasing out this feature.

To implement it yourself, you can use the `freopen` function call from `stdio.h` (or preferably `cstdio`) header.

For example:

```
FILE * my_stdout = freopen ("my_stdout.txt", "wb" /*or "wt"*/, stdout);
FILE * my_stderr = freopen ("my_stderr.txt", "wb" /*or "wt"*/, stderr);
```

From this point on, all `printf`, etc. (all writes to `stdout` and `stderr`,) even `cout` and `cerr` and `clog` are redirected to your files (I'm not sure about whether the `cout` stuff are guaranteed to always work.) You should do this as early as possible in your program, and don't forget to `fclose` them.